# $x$ and $y$ component in unit circle reversed?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, coordinate-systems, vectors

Why is the $x$ component of the $r_2$ vector $\sin \theta$ and $y$ component $\cos \theta$ in the following example as one normally would expect them to be other way around?

[image]

$$
\left.
\begin{array} rr_1=R\left({\phi \atop 1}\right)\\
r_2=-R\left({\sin(\phi) \atop \cos(\phi)}\right)
\end{array}
\right\} \quad r=r_1+r_2=R\left({\phi-\sin(\phi) \atop 1-\cos(\phi)}\right)
$$

Comment: Please include your equations using MathJax, rather than pasting equations as images.

Comment: Notice the orientation theta=0 along y axis.

Comment: I see no theta, but only phi.

Comment: @DanielC Yes, I think the OP wrote $\theta$ instead of $\phi$ (I just continued this with my edit, rather than altering OP's post too significantly).

Comment: It's just convention really when we use cosine for x and some for y as the angle is defined with respect to the x acis, one should always inspect where the angle is defined rather than assuming.

Comment: @Triatticus Could you make me imagine it please? Because I really wanna be able to do that but couldn't yet figure out why x and y coordinates should change when the direction changes although the negative sign makes sense?

Comment: Alright, I got it. I've made the stupid mistake to consider the angle with an imaginary x axis and imagined the components as a reflection over the origin in line with another example.

Comment: @Ali, the sin of an angle is the $opposite$ side divided by the hypotenuse, it is NOT the vertical side divided by the hypotenuse.  Likewise, the cos of an angle is the $adjacent$ side divided by the hypotenuse, it is NOT the horizontal side divided by the hypotenuse.  Whether the x-component is calculated with sin or cos depends on which angle of the triangle you are working with.

Comment: Hello! As mentioned, it is preferrable to use MathJax/LaTeX for displaying equations. You can find a basic tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Because here the angle $\phi$ increases clockwise from the $-y$ direction instead of, as is usually the case, counter-clockwise from the $x$ direction. (Note the minus sign in front of the expression)

Comment: Yes, I guessed that that would be the reason, but couldn't imagine it yet although - sense definitely makes sense. Do you have any resource that makes it intuitive or visualize it?

Comment: This is basic trig but, I always ask myself "if the argument was 0, where would the vector point? That direction should be multiplied by the cosine. If the argument was $\pi/2$, where would the vector point? That direction should be multiplied by the sine." Here, the answers to those questions are "$-y$" and "$-x$", respectively.

Comment: This is nice, thank you Kristoffer.

Comment: short follow-up question: why exactly is the x component of $r_1$ is R*phi? I got the y component but it looks like phi in this case is not our angle but we're still using it.

Comment: It is the angle, in fact. When a wheel rolls, the distance it moves is equal to the angle times the radius - as long as the angle is in radians. Remember this is the formula for the length of a circle segment.